# is it necessary to use php to connect to the MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

is it necessary to use php to connect to the MySQL

i am working the desktop application and do not have a knowledge of php either
is there any in build class or functionality that can be use to connect to the MySQL

although there are many programme present over the internet to do so but unablefind one without the use of php. is there any reference or can i have the step by step example regarding the work.

MySQL config has the default settings. like username is root and password is blank my server name is local host.

Comment: I tagged this as PHP and MySQL and removed the Flex tags.   This question has nothing to do with Flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has nothing to do with PHP, except that they are often bundled together. If you need to access MySQL by itself you can download MySql workbench.

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

If you need a driver for your language google 'language + MySql Driver'

Comment: but how do i connect to the database can i have some reference to connect with it.i am unable to do so do adobe has some in build library that i need to know or some other reference through which i can connect to the database.please need a help on this topic.

Comment: I'm confused. What product are you using exactly? Adobe has many different products. For example, Flash, ColdFusion, etc.

Comment: sir i am using flex4 and i am working where i need to collect data from the sql server which is online. is there a way i can connect to the sql sever and collect the data from there.

Comment: ok sir try this: http://www.flashrealtime.com/flash-builder-4-and-php-data-services/   and http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Simple_MySQL_to_Flex-5561.html

Answer (score 2):

No.  PHP is a programming language.  MySQL is a database.  Install MySQL and type mysql from the command line and you will be connecting to MySQL using mysql.

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

Comment: but how do i connect to the database can i have some reference to connect with it.i am unable to do so do adobe has some in build library that i need to know or some other reference through which i can connect to the database.please need a help on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a desktop application, mysql probably isn't the database you want to use. If you want to store data locally, try something like an embedded sqllite database. If you want to store the data remotely, I STRONGLY recommend to put the database behind an API. That is where something like PHP would come into play. It doesn't have to be PHP though. It can be python, java, ruby, etc.

Whatever you do though, DO NOT talk directly to a remote mysql database from your desktop app. That's just asking to have your db hacked.

Comment: but how do i connect to the database can i have some reference to connect with it.i am unable to do so do adobe has some in build library that i need to know or some other reference through which i can connect to the database.please need a help on this topic.